# Can I write an iOS app with OSX 10.5?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to write an app for my own use on my iPhone (iOS 6.0).  Unfortunately I'm also traveling with my OSX 10.5 laptop with Xcode 3.1.4 loaded.  Is there any way to run an app built with this xcode on my iPhone?  I don't need any feature from a recent iOS and there are plenty of old apps that run just fine and were probably developed with old Xcode versions, but I always get an amber button indicating the iPhone iOS isn't supported when I hit build and run.

Answer (score 1):

The oldest version of xcode that can develop for iOS 6 is xcode 4.5, and for running xcode 4.5 you need to have MAC OS 10.7.4 or later version

Answer (score 1):

Sorry man, You can't.

You need Xcode4 and Lion for iOS6 development.

**EDIT:**

Now(2014 AD) Apple doesn't allow any app developed using below Xcode 5, so you need to have Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

No. To develop for a modern iPhone, you need an Intel mac, and I doubt that a laptop with 10.5 is an Intel Mac (or that 10.5 even supports x86). Also, Xcode versions are correlated to API versions, if you haven't noticed, so even if possible, you'd probably only be able to use the 3.0 APIs, which are now not even usable because of the multitasking introduced in 4.0.

Short answer: No.

Comment: Actually, Apple switched to Intel on the laptops a long time ago (>7 years) so an upgrade is possible.  Looks like that's what I'll need to do if I feel like developing apps while on the road...